# PHP MYSQL Query not fetching multiple WHERE Conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search feature that onkeydown gives out suggestions. Currently, the query only fetches from one row of the table customer_name, and I'm trying to have the id row as well to be searched for the suggestions.

so my query syntax looks likes this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_name OR id like'%".$search."%' LIMIT 5";
```

But the above query will only fetches from the second table name i.e., id but not both.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but `WHERE customer_name` will always evaluate to `true` and thus include all records. You need to specify *what* `customer_name` should be compared to.

Correct query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM customers 
    WHERE customer_name LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR id LIKE '%".$search."%'
LIMIT 5;
```

As an important security tip, you should look into [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) instead of mixing data with your queries. Doing so leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.